# how to get xls file from a ZipArchiveEntry EPPlus C#

Tags: c#, excel, zip, blazor, epplus

i'am trying to get an xls file from an ZipArchive but cant get it with EPPLUS

```
  foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                {
                    if (entry != null)
                    {                        
                        string filepath = entry.FullName;
                        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filepath);
                        
                        //here i got the excel package with the xls file inside the excelPackage 
                        using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
                        {                            
                      //but here impossible de get the worksheet or workbook inside or anything else    
                            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();
                            int totalColomn = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                            int nbrsheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Count();
                        }
                    }
               }
```

[the ExcelPackage i get in debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3QI6.png)
i see the xls file on debug inside the excelpackage but just when i try to get worksheet it exit without exception code....

same here when trying with entryStream

```
                        using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                        {
                       //Cant even get the excelpackage, it crash here without exception
                            using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(entryStream))
                            {
                                ExcelWorksheet worksheetest = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();
                            }
                        }
```

the stream here seem also strange ...
[entryStream Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZhIL.png)

Working with .NET CORE Blazor ServerSide, ePPLUS 4.5

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the problem.

it was that i tried to get an xls file and the epplus library dont work with it...
you have to be careful, EPplus dont work with xls file

So , your solution Jeff is working, it was my fault, didn't specified the extension of my excel file... sorry

-> EPlus with an .xlsx OK,  not .xls

My bad.
Thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

`entry.FullName` refers to the full path to the file *inside the zip archive*, while `FileInfo` describes a file in the filesystem of the OS, which is a completely different thing. You haven't extracted anything to the OS filesystem yet, so the `FileInfo` won't refer to a file that actually exists.

Try the `ExcelPackage` constructor that takes a `Stream`, which you can get directly from a `ZipArchiveEntry`:

```cs
using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
{
    using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(entryStream))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea @Jeff but still not working 
it crash just here:
using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(entryStream))
without exception code.... seems dont want to put into the excelpackage and the entryStream seem not good too cause lot of redcross on debug on .Length, .Position, .Read, .Write